# Add file in ANT build (Tomcat server)

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I have an ANT build that I need to setup so on deployment of the .war a certain file will be placed in a specific location. Currently my ant builds the war as follows...

```
<target name="war" depends="jar">

    <war destfile="${deploy}/file.war" webxml="${web-inf}/web.xml">

        <fileset dir="${WebRoot}">
            <include name="**/*.vm" />
            <include name="**/*.js" />
            <include name="**/*.jsp" />
            <include name="**/*.html" />
            <include name="**/*.css" />
            <include name="**/*.gif" />
            <include name="**/*.jpg" />
            <include name="**/*.png" />
            <include name="**/*.tld" />
            <include name="**/applicationContext*.xml" />
            <include name="**/jpivot/**" />
            <include name="**/wcf/**" />
            <include name="**/platform/**" />
            <include name="**/Reports/**" />
        </fileset>

        <lib dir="${web-inf.lib}" />

    </war>

</target>
```

The file I need is called Scriptlet.class and it needs to be in WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/

I've tried several things to get this to work and have yet to find one that works... if anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `classes` element to put a file in `WEB-INF/classes` :

```
<target name="war" depends="jar">
    <war destfile="${deploy}/file.war" webxml="${web-inf}/web.xml">
        <classes dir="${web-inf.classes}">
          <include name="**/Scriptlet.class"/>
        </classes>
        <fileset dir="${WebRoot}">
            <include name="**/*.vm" />
            <include name="**/*.js" />
            <include name="**/*.jsp" />
            <include name="**/*.html" />
            <include name="**/*.css" />
            <include name="**/*.gif" />
            <include name="**/*.jpg" />
            <include name="**/*.png" />
            <include name="**/*.tld" />
            <include name="**/applicationContext*.xml" />
            <include name="**/jpivot/**" />
            <include name="**/wcf/**" />
            <include name="**/platform/**" />
            <include name="**/Reports/**" />
        </fileset>
        <lib dir="${web-inf.lib}" />
    </war>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nested `<classes>` element to specify a FileSet to appear in `WEB-INF/classes`. Take a look at [the manual page on the `<war>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html).

Comment: So... <classes dir="blah/blah"> the dir in this tag would point to the folder where my file is originally located?

Comment: should point to the location of your compiled output (the .class files) - try it and see if it works?